# How to Filter DataGridView when bound to a linq query result that is linked to an EF4 Entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datagridview, filter

I have a `DataGridView` that bound to a Entity Context like below

```
var leader = from l in myEntity.Leaders
                             select new { l.TeamName, ,l.Name ,l.Family, l.InsuranceNumber, l.Mobile };
DataGridView1.DataSource = leader;
```

now, i want to filter DataGridView rows, for example

```
where Name like 'A%'
```

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ to filter your collection:

```
var filteredLeaders = leader.Where(o=>o.Name.StartsWith("A"));
```

Then rebind your grid:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = filteredLeaders;
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq to SQL is usefull.

There are a very forms

```
var x = from T in db.Table where [usual where stuff goes here];
```